# overflow hidden below not top in css

Tags: css, overflow

`overflow-y:hidden` will hide the view both upper part and lower part. Can we just show upper part but not lower part.
Now I like something like this `overflow-y-top:visible; overflow-y-bottom:hidden;`
Similarly `overflow-x-left:visible;overflow-x-right:hidden`
So is there something we can do in css?

Specific problem mine:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="arrow">▲</div>
   <div id="content">id="toggle_view">view more</div>
   <div id="content1"> this is any thext</div>
   <div id="content2"> this is any thext</div>
   <div id="content3"> this is any thext</div>
   <div id="content4"> this is any thext</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#main {overflow-y:hidden;height:100px;position:relative}
#arrow {position:absolute;top:-30px;}
#toggle_view{position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;}
```

Now I want to make the content hidden not the arrow.
So Is there some technique to make just the below portion of div hidden not top?

Comment: why don't you just use `display:none` for #content?

Comment: I want to animate through the content with view more and view less

Comment: Are you trying to build a toggle switch to show/hide the content?

Comment: @MarcAudet see my update, I want to toggle by clicking view_more.

Comment: Can you link an example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could add padding to the top of the element for however much you want displayed, This could then change to however much you need using javascript. If I understand correctly though, what you're looking for is that the arrow/viewmore is always displayed. so adding a `padding-top: 20px;` or whatever measurement unit you like should work

I added some simple javascript here just to make it work. You probably want animations and all that...

See this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KPbLY/85/

To have the background not go into the padding (as mentioned in the comments) use another nested div such as:

http://jsfiddle.net/KPbLY/87/

Comment: Right now it works fine. But if the element have its `background-color`, the arrow looks inside the element.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the HTML code first. You want:

```
<div id="arrow">▲ (view less)</div>
<div id="main">
   <div id="content1">text from #content1</div>
   <div id="content2">text from #content2</div>
   <div id="content3">text from #content3</div>
   <div id="content4">text from #content4</div>
</div>
<div id="toggle_view">view more</div>
```

Then for the CSS, you want:

```
#main {overflow-y:hidden;height:100px;position:relative}
#arrow {cursor: pointer;}
#toggle_view{ cursor: pointer;}
.inactive { color: gray; }
```

It's really hard to tell you can click something if there's no `cursor:pointer`. Also, we want to indicate to the users when a button is inactive (ex. it's useless to click "view more" if you're already viewing every

All righty, let's get to the JavaScript. You mentioned you're using a library, but not which one, so I'll just assume jQuery. First, we need to set our variables:

```
var heightOfMain = $('#main').height();
var heightOfContent1 = $('#content1').height();
var differenceInHeight = heightOfMain - heightOfContent1;
```

Then, when clicking on `#arrow`, we want to change the height of `#main` to remove `#content2`, `#content3`, and `#content4`, leaving only `#content1` behind (basically, we want to "remove" a height equal to `differenceInHeight`). We also want to then inactivate `#arrow`, since there's no point in saying "view less" if you're already viewing less. Finally, we want to make sure that "view more" is active (since we'll be toggling that later).

```
$('#arrow').click(function() {

    $('#main').animate({
        height: heightOfContent1 
    });  
     $(this).addClass('inactive');
     $('#toggle_view').removeClass('inactive');
});
```

Finally, we want to enable `#toggle_view`. When clicking it, we want to re-add the height that we took off (`differenceInHeight`). Then, since we have everything already viewed, we can inactivate "view more". Finally, we need to activate "view less" again.

```
$('#toggle_view').click(function() {

    //you want to remove contents 2 through 4, which have a combined height
    //of differenceInHeight
    $('#main').animate({
        height: differenceInHeight });  
        $(this).hide();
        $('#arrow').show();

});
```

For everything put together, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YUYa/13/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#content {
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
#content {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want something that works like this:

```
<div class="show-panel">
   <div class="arrow">&#9650;</div>
   <div class="content">This is some content... 
                        several paragraphs for example.</div>
</div>
```

with the following jQuery action:

```
$(".arrow").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Fiddle Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/bQ8G3/

You can add a CSS style to initially hide the content if that is desired.  The cleanest way of doing this is wrapping the elements to be shown/hidden in a parent element and then showing/hiding the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can used to `css`

**As like this**

```
#main {overflow-y:hidden;height:100px;position:relative; background:red;}

#toggle_view{position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;}

#arrow {position:absolute;top:50px;right:0;background:green;padding:5px; cursor:pointer;z-index:2;}
#main > #arrow ~ div{display:none;}
#main > #arrow:focus ~ div, #main > #arrow:hover ~ div{display:block;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mjSK/)**

Comment: Thank you for your effort but that don't solve my problem. See edit on my post.